# Document compiling in online editor but not in TeXworks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling

I have the following code, which compiles with no errors in the online editor OverLeaf, but it does not compile in the editor TeXworks that I have on my computer.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}


\tikzset{Karl’s grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

   \draw[Karl’s grid] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried creating a fresh document and ran this code, but it still didn't compile.

Before I ever ran this code, I did mess around a little bit with "help lines" style as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499776/where-is-my-understanding-of-tikz-styles-wrong), so I am not sure if I possibly changed the help lines style in the package installed on my computer?

The console output says

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \OT1\textquoteright 
l.7 ...��s grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

?
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove special characters like `’` from key name:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}


\tikzset{Karls grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

   \draw[Karls grid] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I may ask, did the output console help you diagnose this problem? If so, how?

Comment: @Ovi The error is where the line break in the error message is. The second line starts with `s grid`, so the error must be the letter in front of that